# How do I find the analytical solutions to Lotka Volterra equations?

Tags: calculus

The Lotka Volterra equations are used to calculate the rate of change of predator, $y$, and prey, $x$, populations over time ($t$),and are shown below:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=ax-bxy$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-cy+dxy$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are parameters, and $x$ and $y$ are greater than zero.

I have been looking at online methods, used by mathematicians, however, researchers seem to be solving the parameters through computer softwares like Matlab and Maple. I could not find analytic i.e algebraic solutions to the parameters. My question is,can the parameters be determined algebraically? As a high school student, my school does not allow me to use high tech computer softwares like maple, and I have been to told find the parameters using algebra. However, online research and mathematical literature seems to suggest, that the only way to determine the parameters is through a computer analyses, and not with algebraic rigour.

It would be great, if I could get some sort of a direction, as to what I should do to figure out what the parameters are through algebra, if the population of the prey oscillates between 200 and 400 sheep and the predator population oscillates between 50 and 100.

Comment: Are the equations written correctly? Did you mean $a x$?

Comment: @Moo Hey, thanks! It was a mistake. I fixed it :)

Comment: You can't find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ explicitly, but you can find a constant of motion $V(x,y) = \text{constant}$. See here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#A_simple_example

Comment: @Hans Lundwark Thankyou! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853612/how-to-adjust-the-parameters-of-lotka-volterra-equations-to-fit-the-extremal-val                         What do you think of the method presented here as an answer for the calculation of the parameters.?

Comment: @HansLundmark I have already derived the linear function for the Lotka Volterra equations in terms of V(x,y)=constant; V (x,y)=constant. But the problem is still there, is there a method for calculating the parameters algebraically?

Comment: First comment: If you look at the reputation of the answerer (user Did) you may guess (and I can confirm that it's true) that his answers are always trustworthy. Second comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. What does “delivered the linear function mean”?

Comment: @HansLundmark I mean that I have in my paper, by integrating dx/dy, obtained the following result C= by-alny+dx-clnx, where C is the integration constant, however how do I find the values of a, b, c, and d? Sorry, but this is so confusing.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what Did's answer to that other question explains? (The highlighted formulas towards the end: $a=\cdots$, $b=\cdots$, etc.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Alright, this means that Did's solution is the only liable method for the parameters determination. I was just looking for perhaps an alternative approach to the solution of the parameters, since I think that Did jumps very quickly from one explanation to the next, missing out several steps in between, e.g. his introduction of the equations; h(z)=lnz/(z-1) and g(z)=z-1-lnz seems abrupt, and ''out of the blue''. Perhaps, you would know, as to how he came up with these expressions? I unfortunately, dont have a high enough reputation to ask him these questions myself as comments.